# Error while installing nodemon from terminal ? I actually had the same problem while updating Nodejs too

Tags: node.js, terminal, nodemon

this is the error thrown, I had the same problem while updating Nodejs, however, I managed to update it using the download option. but still having this every time I try installing   nodemon  from terminal

```
JuJu:/ juri$ npm install -g nodemon
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/juri/.npm/_logs/2020-06-21T11_25_30_937Z-debug.log
JuJu:/ juri$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you can use

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

if you are a sudoer..

Answer (score 1):

[Try using nvm to reinstall node.](https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b) Worked for me.

To install nvm:
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash`

To check it's installed:
`command -v nvm`

To install node:
`nvm install node` or `nvm install <SPECIFIC_NODE_VERSION>`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem change the owner of the folder. Run this command:

> sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a macbook you need to give administrative power to the terminal hence use::

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```